# How to select nested DOM elements inside 'ul' element

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools

I am looking for a way to collect all `<a>` tags and load then in an array using Mootool 1.1 or pure javascript.

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Group One</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">I want</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">I want too</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Group Two</a>
         <ul>
           <li"><a href="#">I want</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">I want too</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
     </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Edit Solution:

Thank you all, your responses have helped me find a more precise solution.

Mootools 1.1: @ Oskar

```
$$("ul.menu ul li ul li a");
```

@ Dimitar

```
document.getElements("ul.menu ul li ul li a");
```

Keep Geeking :)

Comment: `document.getElemnts` is mootools, not native javascript - $$ aliases to that. :) there's a school of thought that being too precise in the selectors is not always leading to the best performance results or maintainability - unless you need to be as precise in order to exclude different links, i think it's overkill. a more elegant solution and certainly faster performing would be so assign a class to the links themselves, bit we don't always get to change the markup. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// for the links of the first ul.menu on the page
var menuLinks = document.getElement("ul.menu").getElements("a");
// or you can get all links children of all uls with class menu
var menuLinks = document.getElements("ul.menu a");
```

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo use document.querySelector(); instead. 

EG: `document.querySelector("ul.menu a");`

Comment: ```VM231:1 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElements is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:10```

Comment: I wonder what make u make that weird insulting comment .. lack of basic decency / good upbringing ?

Comment: This is working just for element type and class. Can you advise to select for example <p> element with id nested in multiple nested div?

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure if you want to limit the action somehow, but getting all anchor elements in the page is easy:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

If you want to limit your search inside an element, set an id on that element so that you can easily find it, and use the `getElementsByTagName` on the element:

```
var links = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however document.getElementsByTagName will just select all the links in the document and all i want to do is select main menu links.

Comment: @Q_the_novice: Then set an id on the menu element so that you can use the `getElementById` method to find it, then use the `getElementsByTagName` method on that element to find the links inside it.

Answer (score 2):

`$$('.menu a')`

Comment: $$ is being deprecated but it's an alias for `this.document.getElements()` - this selector is a bit broad though. what if you have `<div class="menu">` elsewhere

Comment: @Dimitar: The current Joomla! CMS version(1.5) uses mootools 1.1, so until Joomla! 1.6(uses mootools 1.2) is officially released the $$ selector will still be useful to developers.

Also check my edit at the top.